# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "..." does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want my User objects in Django to be linked to a Client object (which I create). To do so I extend the User model with a one-to-one link with a Profile class (which I create)
class Profile that links User & Client. I followed the instructions from https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html So far so good.

However when I create a User object I dont have access by default to  I want my User objects

My models.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

[...]

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    [...]

class Profile(models.Model):
    need_setup = Client.objects.get(name='NEED TO ADD CLIENT IN ADMIN > PROFILES')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

The problem comes when I make my migrations / runserver (my app is called 'dashboard'):
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "dashboard_client" does not exist LINE 1: ...nque_id", "dashboard_client"."date_creation" FROM "dashboard...`
because of the `need_setup = Client.objects.get(name='NEED TO ADD CLIENT IN ADMIN > PROFILES')` (no problems if I comment it out).

I can work around the problem by manually creating a client in the db called 'NEED TO ADD CLIENT IN ADMIN > PROFILES' and then run my migrations and deploy but I'm looking for a better way of doing this, especially when I deploy from scratch in prod.

I tried to override the `def ready(self)` function in apps.py, which is a function that runs when the apps boots. Unfortunately it needs to have the correct models.py before running.

Your thoughts and ideas are appreciated!

Comment: So, your problem here is that you are trying to `get` an instance of a `Client` in your `Profile` model.  At the outset, you don't actually have any client instances, so your call to `Client.objects.get()` is rightfully returning an error.  This is why this problem is fixed when you manually add a client to the DB that matches that name.  I'm unsure what your goal is with the `need_setup` field, but as it is right now, it's not actually a field, it's a queryset, which should not be in a Model.  If you could clear up what `need_setup` is supposed to be, we can probably figure out how to fix it

Comment: I agree with @rchurch4. It seems like you want to know which Profile objects have been newly created with a `user` from the post-save signal `create_user_profile`. In that case, you can simply set `need_setup` as a BooleanField with a default value of `True`. Then, override the `save` method to check if the object has a `client` linked. If `client` is still null, keep `need_setup` as True, otherwise set to False.

Comment: yep, exactly what I was going for ^

Comment: you both are legends thank you very much. I did implement the idea from @Scratch'N'Purr - can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as answered? Cheers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your case, you want to:

1. Trigger a creation of a Profile object after a User is created and have the Profile object linked to the user (already done with your post-save signal).
2. Determine whether the profile object needs to be configured with a `client` (the problem you want to resolve)

In this case, you set your `need_setup` field as a BooleanField with an attribute of `default=True`. This means that any Profile objects that are newly created will by default need to be set up. For security measure, you can add the attribute `editable=False` so that the field can't be modified externally.

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    need_setup = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Next, you override the model's `save` method to toggle the boolean field based on whether `client` is populated or not.

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    need_setup = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.client is None:
            self.need_setup = True
        else:
            self.need_setup = False

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

An alternative solution is using python's `@property`. With this solution, you basically set `need_setup` as a property instead of a field. This has the advantage of not having to create a field on the database level. The downside of this solution is that you can't use it in django querysets, e.g. `Profile.objects.filter(need_setup=True)`, because django querysets use database fields.

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    @property
    def need_setup(self):
        return not bool(self.client)
```